# Как управлять службами, как зашить в код программы права админа?

Tags: c#, администрирование, службы

Часто возникают проблемы с печатью у пользователей, которые я решаю в основном перезапуском spooler. Решил написать утилитку, которая делала бы это сама, но проблема в том, что запускать ее должны пользователи, а у них прав админа, т.е. прав для управления службами нету. Как зашить в код программы привелегии админа? Не нашел параметр, который бы запрашивал от какого пользователя проводить изменения со службами

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;


namespace ManagePrintService
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController ser = new         
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Spooler");
        textBox1.Text = ser.DisplayName;
        ser.Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ser.Start();
        textBox1.Text = "succes";

    }
}
}
```

Comment: [ProcessStartInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo)

Comment: Если пользователям надо перезапускать spooler - значит, правильнее всего разрешить им это делать, а не давать пароль админа. Ищите как задавать ACL для служб.

Comment: Вот тут есть решения, но они на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4436558/4340086

Comment: @PavelMayorov так я и не хочу давать пароль админа, хочу спрятать( вшить в код) - легче было бы в бат файлике сделал все то же самое, но бат файл некоторые умники могут расковырять, а скомпилированный exe  нет.

Comment: В .Net код вы безопасно не вшьете пароль админа, любой Net декомпилер выдаст весь ваш код с потрохами. Только если с обфускацией, но и то не факт. Сделайте сервис, который запускается от админа, и к нему отдельной программой графический интерфейс с кнопкой, который подключается через какой нть протокол.

Comment: @ГеннадийП , мне не нужно очень безопасно - ни о каких декомпилерах ребята не слышали, а в коде будет не главный админ а специально созданный для этих манипуляций юзер с повышенными правами. А то, что вы написали 'Сделайте сервис, который запускается от админа, и к нему отдельной программой графический интерфейс с кнопкой, который подключается через какой нть протокол' я не понял от слова -совсем.

Comment: @elislavkat Ну, делаете одну программу сервисом(или автоматический запуск в фоне из планировщика, не важно), который запускается от админа. Вторую делаете клиентом, и например через WCF общение между ними. Клиент подключается к сервису, дает команду, сервис перезапускает Spooler.

Comment: Собственно, Павел Майоров дал правильный ответ. В Вашем случае решение задачи требует повышения привилегий пользователю. Логично, что в исполнимый файл это прописать нельзя  - иначе это будет exploit. Значит, нужно настроить клиента так, чтобы пользователь мог запускать и останавливать нужный сервис. Лично я использовал опробованное решение через конфигурирование сервиса с помощью системной утилиты [sc.exe](http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/). Решение совпадает с ссылкой, выданной ранее. В ссылке, приложенной мною, решение указано для службы печати.

Answer (score 2):

В `Windows` есть планировщик задач, где можно задать админскую учетку.

Можно попробовать провернуть такой трюк:

Создаем задачу с ручным запуском и указываем там учетку админа и указываем путь к вашей программе. Можно воспользоваться `SCHTASKS` и через `CMD` создать.

Далее конструируем батник, который `SCHTASKS`, где указываем имя вашей задачи, которая будет запускать по нажатию на батник.

И теперь при запуске этого ярлыка, будет запускаться задача с админскими привилегиями, которая будет запускать вашу программу с такими же привелегиями.

Сам я не пробовал, но в теории это должно работать.

Comment: попробую, но похожие манипуляции у меня не сработали как то раз.

Comment: @elislavkat,должны работать. Только учти что он приоритет понижает.

Comment: @Qwertiy _Планировщику заданий не удается запустить экземпляр "{2075dede-d863-47af-851d-f8817dc18cca}" задачи "\vjz\1" для пользователя "domain\admin". Дополнительные сведения: значение ошибки: 2147942405._

Comment: А если руками через планировщик без батника?

Comment: @iluxa1810 , как раз в планировщике и кликаю - выполнить.

Comment: @elislavkat, точно все верно указали? А если не вашу программу запускать, а какой-нибудь стандартный калькулятор.

Comment: @elislavkat, пути проверяй.

Comment: @iluxa1810 даже если "показать сообщение" - ничего не делает.  результат  последнего запуска 0x1 . Запускаю задачу но ничего не происходит. завершаю

Comment: @elislavkat, а на диск C пробовали все класть? Кириллица в путях есть? Попробуйте все положить в корень диска С без кириллицы.

Comment: Задача на английском называется? У батников проблема с кириллицей, если не сохранить его в OEM866.